# Populate dynamic HTML table from MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, foreach, while-loop

At the moment I got incomplete what I need, how can I continue to display the `SELECT` results in their respective tables?

As you can see in the example above - there is a image at the end of topic - the first dynamically generated table was populated with your right data. You can see by the title of the table that refers to the last column Event.

But in the other tables I can not generate the loop.

I'm in the right way ?

**What I want to do:**

I have two tables in MySQL one with names *Events* and other *Tickets*. They have in common a column named *event* with the same data. In HTML tables generated according to the number of rows in the *Events* table, I wanted to select the information from the *Tickets* table and put in their respective HTML tables, where the title of each is a column named *event* in the *Events* table.

```html
<?php

include 'conection.php';

$tickets = $con->prepare("SELECT tickets.chair, tickets.name, tickets.event, events.event FROM tickets INNER JOIN events ON tickets.event = events.event");
$tickets ->execute();

$events = $con->prepare("SELECT event FROM events");
$events ->execute();

?>


<!doctype html>

<html>
  <body>
        
                <?php 


foreach($events as $evt){        

echo " <div class='box[]'>
                       
       <table border='1px'>
         
         <thread>
             
               <th> ".$evt['event']."   </th>
                
               <tr>
                         <th>chair</th>
                         <th>name</th>
                         <th>event</th>
               </tr> 
   
         </thread> ";
    
    while ($ingr = $tickets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        
        if(($tck['event']) === ($evt['evento'] )){
         
    echo " <tbody> ";
    echo " <tr>   ";                    
     
      echo "<td>" .$ingr['chair'].   "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$ingr['name'].   "</td>";
      echo "<td>" .$ingr['event']. "</td>";
      
     
  }}}
        
    echo " </tr>     ";                             
    echo " </tbody>  ";    
        
    echo " </table> ";                     
    echo "</div>";

?>



 </body>
</html>
```

> **Exemple**

*I cant display image yet, but this is what iam done for now.*

[Figure of the code executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMbhz.png)

Comment: drop the `<table>` tag outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some cleaning up.

1. The `<thead>` tag is a "table head", not a "thread" :)
2. Using a `<th>` outside of the `<tr>` will not work; move the event name into a header (`<h2>` or something) above your table.
3. You are using the field name 'evento' when you selected the field 'event'.

To answer your main question: you are seeing only one set of tickets because you run through the whole set of tickets when you search for the right ones for your first event. This way, `$tickets` has been exhausted by the time you want to get the tickets for the second event. You could try putting the ticket information in a variable after selecting (using `$tickets->fetchAll`), then using that variable in your loop instead of the `$tickets` resultset.

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks for the cleaning tips, about the 3º, am just translate some words of my project to post here to avoid " strange " words, and i forget to change this one :P